# How do you concat two literal strings in a CMake expression?

Tags: string, syntax, cmake, string-concatenation

I've just read this:

[How do you concatenate string in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001198/how-do-you-concatenate-string-in-cmake)

which is close to what I want, but not quite there. I want to concatenate two literal strings, without the concatenation would not be its own command. In programming language terms - I want to concatenate literal strings within an expression.

Is this possible? (I don't mind a high CMake version requirement.)

Note: This is *not* a question about breaking a single string onto multiple lines.

Comment: The accepted answer to the question you linked seems already to demonstrate exactly what you describe.  Although it *also* demonstrates assigning the result to a variable, to the best of my knowledge that part is not essential.  If you think differently then perhaps a [mcve] would clarify what you're asking.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: See edit. I should have explained why that one's not a solution for me either. As for an MCVE - you can only ask for an example if one can be provided. I'm asking "how to do X?" - I cann't give an example. If you're asking "what do you need this for"? Let's just say it's curiosity + programming style.

Comment: I still don't follow.  If you have *literal* strings to concatenate, then what prevents you from just writing the concatenation as a single string?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I didn't say something prevents me from doing so. But to humor you: Suppose that they're long and I want them on separate lines.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what you're asking.  It sounds like it's actually more about how to *split* long strings across multiple lines, and that already has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637539/how-to-split-strings-across-multiple-lines-in-cmake/16703203).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split strings across multiple lines in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637539/how-to-split-strings-across-multiple-lines-in-cmake)

Comment: @JohnBollinger: That's not what I asked, and stop trying to manipulate me/my question.

Comment: I am not trying to manipulate anything, but since we seem unable to communicate I will be moving on now.  I hope you get an answer that satisfies you.

Comment: Like @JohnBollinger, I don't see your point. Why [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18003562/3440745) to the referenced question does not answer your question? And why the referenced question is not a duplicate of yours? An example would be really helpful for understand the question. Not [mcve], but an example of **input** and which **output** (effect) you want to achieve.

Comment: This is really vague. `string(CONCAT <output variable> [<input>...])` concatenates the strings. It's in the linked question and answer.  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/manual/cmake-language.7.html doesn't specify much other than commands and their arguments. What other programming expression are you expecting to exist?

Comment: @Fred: I'm looking for something which does not involve a named output variable for the concatenation. I'm looking for something like a concatenation operator on strings.

Comment: @einpoklum According to the link I posted there is none specified in the language.

Comment: @Fred: Ok, then - can you make that an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMake language http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/manual/cmake-language.7.html specification does not specify a way to concatenate string literals.

`string(CONCAT <output variable> [<input>...])` can be used to concatenate the input arguments and assign it to a new variable.  This is different from the `set` command that would create a list based on the input arguments.